# Does $L^\infty$ convergence imply convergent of an Integral

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be compact, $\alpha\in L^\infty([0,T];A)$ and $\alpha_n\subset L^\infty([0,T];A)$ with $\alpha_n\rightarrow \alpha$ in $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. Let also $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^d$ be continuous.

Does $\int_0^T\|f(\alpha_n(s))-f(\alpha(s))\|ds \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

If $\alpha_n$ would be continuous this wouldn't be a problem, because $\alpha_n$ would converge pointwise and, hence, $\|f(\alpha_n(s))-f(\alpha(s))\|\rightarrow 0$ for all $s\in[0,T]$. This certaintly does not work here, since we have only the measurability of $\alpha_n$. If we can show that $\text{ess}\sup_{s\in[0,T]}\|f(\alpha_n(s))-f(\alpha(s))\|\rightarrow 0$, also the integral converges to zero. Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is uniformly continuous. But how does it imply that the integral converge? Can you be a bit more precise please?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.